# Using WHERE IN (...) with PDO doesn't work when the string is bound

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a query that looks like this:

```
  UPDATE table SET column = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
  WHERE id IN (:idString)
```

Where `idString` is a string of comma separated ids and is passed to `execute()` in an array. To my surprise, when this query is executed, only the row with the first id in `idString` is updated.

After banging my head against the wall for a while, I finally decided to try it like this:

```
  UPDATE table SET column = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
  WHERE id IN (' . $idString . ')
```

The second query works as expected.

Why won't the query work when I bind the string of ids using PDO?

Comment: Alternatively use `FIND_IN_SET()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL, the string

```
'1,2,3,5,12'
```

Is a single value, and casting it in a numeric context, it will just have the value of the leading digits, so just the value `1`.

This is much different from the set of multiple values:

```
'1', '2', '3', '5', '12'
```

Any time you use bound parameters, whatever you pass as the parameter value becomes just one single value, even if you pass a string of comma-separated values.

If you want to pass a set of multiple values to parameters in your SQL query, you must have multiple parameter placeholders:

```
UPDATE table SET column = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
WHERE id IN (:id1, :id2, :id3, :id4, :id5)
```

Then explode your string of values and pass them as an array:

```
$idlist = array('id1' => 1, 'id2' => 2, 'id3' => 3, 'id4' => 5, 'id5' => 12);
$pdoStmt->execute($idlist);
```

For cases like this, I would recommend using *positional parameters* instead of named parameters, because you can pass a simple array instead of an associative array:

```
$pdoStmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE table SET column = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
    WHERE id IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$idlist = explode(",", "1,2,3,5,12");
$pdoStmt->execute($idlist);
```

---

@mario adds a comment that you can use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set). That query would look allow you to pass one string formatted as a comma-separated string of values:

```
$pdoStmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE table SET column = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, :idString)");
$pdoStmt->execute(["idString" => "1,2,3,5,12"]);
```

However, I usually don't recommend that function because it spoils any chance of using an index to narrow down the search. It will literally have to examine every row in the table, and during an UPDATE that means it has to **lock** every row in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Your working solution is not good as it's subject to `SQL INJECTION`.
The reason it's not working is because you are allocating an array,  instead of  plain comma separated values.

You have to use `implode` to separate the values of the array,  and then assign the comma separated values to a variable wich can be used by `pdo`.

Otherwise you can use instead of `: $idString`,  `? in the select statement,  and executing the prepared statement from and array which holds the $idString.`

```
 $query=$db->prepare("Select a From table where b =? order by 1;");
 $query->execute(array($idString));
```

Comment: +1 Good point about SQL injection. In my case I'm using integer row IDs retrieved from a previous query, so it's safe, but generally speaking your absolutely right that using unbound variables is dangerous..

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass a string as a set to a prepared statement. MySQL is trying to execute the query

```
-- assuming idString is "1,2,3,4,5"
UPDATE table SET column = UNIX_TIMESTAMP() WHERE id IN ("1,2,3,4,5");
```

instead of

```
UPDATE table SET column = UNIX_TIMESTAMP() WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5);
```

you'll have to either use the statement

```
UPDATE table SET column = UNIX_TIMESTAMP() WHERE id == ?
```

and execute it for however many id's you have or prepare the statement by injecting id string into the query

Answer (score 0):

When binding, PDO expects a single value. Something like this will work, given your $idString above (though if you have the source array, even better!):

```
$ids = explode(',', $idString);
$placeholders = implode(', id', array_keys($ids));
if($placeholders) {
    $placeholders = 'id' . $placeholders;
    $sql = "UPDATE table SET column = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
         WHERE id IN ({$placeholders})";

    // prepare your statement, yielding "$st", a \PDOStatement
    $st = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    // bind every placeholder
    foreach($ids as $key => $id) {
        $st->bindValue("id{$key}", $id);
    }

    // execute
    $st->execute();
}
```