# PHP - Not showing all rows from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code which is supposed to get several records from the database. When the query is ran in phpmyadmin it displays the rows fine, but on the page it only displays the first item

I've echo'd the $cardList array and its shows the correct ids

```
$cards = array($get['card1'], $get['card2'], $get['card3'], $get['card4'], $get['card5'], $get['card6'], $get['card7'], $get['card8'], $get['card9'], $get['card10']);

foreach($cards as $card) {
    if($card != "0")
        $cardList[] = $card;
}

$sql = "SELECT mc.id, d.deckName, c.cardNumber
    FROM me_member_cards AS mc
    LEFT JOIN me_cards AS c ON c.id = mc.cardID
    LEFT JOIN me_decks AS d ON d.deckName = c.deckName
    WHERE mc.id in (:cardsList)";

$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->bindValue(':cardsList', implode(',' , $cardList));
$q->execute();
if($q->errorCode() != 0) {
     $errors = $q->errorInfo();
         echo($errors[2]);
}
foreach ($q->fetchAll() as $row) {
    echo $row['id'] . " - " . $row['deckName'] . " " . $row['cardNumber'] . "<br/>";
}
```

echoing the query gives

```
SELECT mc.id, d.deckName, c.cardNumber FROM me_member_cards AS mc LEFT JOIN me_cards AS c ON c.id = mc.cardID LEFT JOIN me_decks AS d ON d.deckName = c.deckName WHERE mc.id in (29,64,53,13,38,13,8)
```

Comment: Not sure how you think you echoed the query, but `:cardsList` placeholder isn't working the way you think it does.

Comment: Binding a number of parameters with one placeholder is a __non-working__ approach.

Comment: echo'd using

 echo "SELECT mc.id, d.deckName, c.cardNumber
  FROM me_member_cards AS mc
  LEFT JOIN me_cards AS c ON c.id = mc.cardID
  LEFT JOIN me_decks AS d ON d.deckName = c.deckName
  WHERE mc.id in (".implode(',' , $cardList).")";

Comment: A similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174161/using-where-in-with-pdo-doesnt-work-when-the-string-is-bound

Comment: @CeriTurner Yeah, that's not how placeholders work. Your echo and your prepared statement are not the same. Using prepared statements is not a simple variable replacement.

Comment: Yeah, still learning having come from normal mysql. How would i go about this? i know i can make each value a parameter but there is a random amount of ids (max 10)

Comment: It's not a random amount when you get to that point in the code. When it hits that, you know exactly how many items are in the array `count($cardList)`, so you can do a `str_repeat` or similar to generate the separated placeholders (I'd use `?` rather than named in this case) and then just pass the array into the `execute` rather than using `bindValue`.

Comment: Which actually is one of the examples in the link @u_mulder gave.

Comment: you mean using FIND_IN_SET()? One of the replies says its not the best way to do it with an update which is what will be eventually be done when its finished

Comment: Unrelated, but by simply adding where mc.id != 0 you can eliminate having to define the cardlist array to remove 0's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$cards = array($get['card1'], $get['card2'], $get['card3'], $get['card4'], $get['card5'], $get['card6'], $get['card7'], $get['card8'], $get['card9'], $get['card10']);

$cardList = $placeholderList = [];
foreach ($cards as $key => $card) {
    if ($card != "0") {
        $cardList[':mc_id' . $key] = $card;
    }
}

$sql = "SELECT mc.id, d.deckName, c.cardNumber
    FROM me_member_cards AS mc
    LEFT JOIN me_cards AS c ON c.id = mc.cardID
    LEFT JOIN me_decks AS d ON d.deckName = c.deckName
    WHERE mc.id in (" . implode(',', array_keys($cardList)) . ")";

$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);

array_walk($cardList, function ($value, $placeholder) use ($q) {
    $q->bindValue($placeholder, $value, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
});

// ...
```